# Reasoning behind selecting jQuery versus other JS libraries

Tags: discussion, architecture, jquery

I am interested in finding how the Stack Overflow team came to decide on jQuery as its JavaScript library/toolkit. I am currently working with a development "framework" which supports Dojo natively, but I have a hard time implementing some aspects of our web app, especially UI elements, animations, etc. Since I had a jQuery background before this work, my initial reaction is to disable Dojo and load up jQuery. But I am trying to avoid my personal experience biasing the decision. And since I am sure the Stack Overflow development team did not choose jQuery blindly, I would be very interested in the process behind selecting it.  (Sometimes looking at what really smart people choose is not a bad way to make a decision :)

Comment: Pretty sure this question was much, much shorter when I started looking for the podcast... Given what you've written *after* the first sentence, I feel compelled to redirect you to [this classic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/176324/why-does-everyone-like-jquery-more-than-prototype-script-aculo-us-or-mootools-or), wherein lots and lots of folks with varying amounts of intelligence sound off on the eternal question, "Why jQuery?"

Answer (score 3):

This was [captured in the podcast, way back when...](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/05/podcast-6/)

> **Atwood:** So JQuery is the one [Jarrod](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/3/jarrod-dixon) liked the most and I didn't really have a preference.  So that's what we're using.

-- [podcast transcript](https://stackoverflow.fogbugz.com/default.asp?W4331)

IOW, if you work with Jarrod Dixon and are starting out from scratch, jQuery is a fine choice. If you're not, then this question doesn't really help you.